# returning another class when instantiating a class in python

Tags: python, oop, metaprogramming

I am trying to use logging's [memory handler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#memoryhandler) to buffer log messages to my actual logging handler. You use the memory handler by instantiating it with some arguments, like this:

```
import logging
buffered_handler = logging.handlers.MemoryHandler(capacity=5,target=myActualHandler)
```

However, I don't want my application to have to instantiate a handler from logging directly, or pass any of the arguments; I'd like this code to look like this:

```
import myhandlers
buffered_handler = myhandlers.BufferedRemoteHandler()
```

The question is: how do I do this? I'd like an attempt to instantiate my `BufferedRemoteHandler` to *actually* return logging's MemoryHandler with some specific arguments. I thought of just making `BufferedRemoteHandler` a function which returns the handler I want; is that the correct way? Is there a way to create a class which, when you instantiate it, actually returns a totally different class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your exact question, you may, if you like, override `__new__()` on your subclass to return an instance of a class other than yours.

```
import logging

class BufferedRemoteHandler(object):
   def __new__(cls):
       return logging.handlers.MemoryHandler(capacity=5,target=myActualHandler)
```

But I'd actually suggest the function.

Comment: thanks for answering the question! this looks pretty elegant; are there any other reasons besides simplicity for recommending the function route?

Comment: @Igor, how about the principle of least astonishment?

Comment: I'd agree. Returning an instance of some other class is a kind of surprising outcome for a class instantiation operation.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe point 3 of PEP 8 is the answer:

```
Simple is better than complex.
```

I'd go the function way. Maybe call it something like `get_handler()` (or `get_buffered_remote_handler()`) though, so you realize it is something other than a real class at first glance.

Comment: Usually a function of this type is called a Factory Function. In this case you could refer to it as a Handler Factory

Answer (score 1):

Yes just make it a function. Something like getMemoryHandler(). THat's the best way to do it. Also, if only one instance of MemoryHandler is going to be around you may want to make it a singleton.

Comment: the singleton in this case is already the `logging` module itself; you set it up once with your handlers and settings, and every subsequent instantiation/import uses those.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer you directly, yes, there's `__new__()`.  However, I think what would probably be an easier solution would be to either hard code or allow special handler definitions to be registered to myhandlers.  You'd define a member method for each handler you want in myhandlers that just instantiated the MemoryHandler as you want and returned it.